# Sharepoint list view with Thumbnail image

Tags: list-view, custom-list

Is there any way I can display a list view with a column of a thumbnail image on it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can add a a "Hyperlink or Picture" field, and make its format as "Picture" as the image shown below.

[image]

Comment: Thanks, how would I make it such that the width and length of the image is fixed when it gets displayed as a list view? Currently one of the images is too big..any easy way to force the table cell width permanent?

Comment: You would either have to upload images with similar sizes, or you would need to apply CSS to your list view to make images inside that view of smiliar size.

Comment: If you edit the page where the view is, add a script editor webpart, and put its content as : `<style> .ms-listviewtable img { width: 200px; } </style>` that would do it.

Comment: anyway to make that specific column only 200px, It seems that other images  on the page are set to 200px.....